# Depth from uncalibrated stereo images

Tags: python, matlab

I have rectified the stereo images using uncalibrated rectification in Matlab. Now after having disparities from deep learning models, I am trying to convert it to the depth map. But the baseline and focal length values are taken before rectification. so if I use the formula,

`depth = (b(in m)f(in pixels))/disparity(in pixels)`

the depth image obtained is significantly large in one region and another region it is very less. But instead, if I use a scale factor it seems to produce relative depths. I would like to know what could be the problem here?